# Why there are 2 dashboard appears at the beginning and one of them disappear only after click the button?

Tags: javascript

Currently, I am trying to display 2 dashboard in my website. They are intended to be separated by a toggle button, which means that user should never see them display in a same page.

However, every time I first launch the website, I can always see both first and second dashboards appear on the first page, where should only have the first dashboard. And once I click the toggle button twice and come back to the same page, the second dashboard will disappear. Why is this happening and how to make the second dashboard never appear on the first dashboard's page even from the very beginning?

JavaScript code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"> 
    </script>


    <script>
      function toggle() {
        var x1 = document.getElementById("dashboard1");
        var x2 = document.getElementById("dashboard2");
        var bl = document.getElementById("button1");

        if (x1.style.display === "none") {
          x1.style.display = "block";
          x2.style.display = "none";
          bl.firstChild.data = "To Data B";
        } else {
          x1.style.display = "none";
          x2.style.display = "block";
          bl.firstChild.data = "To Data A";
        }
      }

    function initialize() {

      var containerDiv1 = document.getElementById("dashboard1"),
      url1 = "https://public.tableau.com/views/liveintegration1/Dashboard1",
      options1 = {
                      hideTabs: true,
                      onFirstInteractive: function () {
                          console.log("Run this code when the viz has finished loading.");
                      }
                  };
      var viz1 = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv1, url1, options1);



      var containerDiv2 = document.getElementById("dashboard2"),
      url2 ="https://public.tableau.com/views/LearnEmbeddedAnalytics/SalesOverviewDashboard",
      options2 = {
                      hideTabs: true,
                      onFirstInteractive: function () {
                          console.log("Run this code when the viz has finished loading.");
                      }
                  };
      var viz2 = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv2, url2, options2);

    }

    </script>

    <style>
    #dashboard1 {
      width:800px; 
      height:700px;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    #dashboard2 {
      width:800px; 
      height:700px;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">

    <button id="button1" onclick="toggle()">To Data B</button>

    <div id="dashboard1" style="width:800px; height:700px;"></div>

    <div id="dashboard2" style="width:800px; height:700px;"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: onload is not the same as document.ready. Try Jquery, your function is getting called later. Also apply CSS to the dashboard you want to hide with display:none

Comment: @VisakhVijayan I tried to add display:none as the first answer suggest, although this can remove the second dashboard in the first page, but this will make the second dashboard in the second page also disappear. Any solution to make them display as designed?

Comment: If you have different URLs you can run a function and check which URL it is. If it's dashboard1Url add a display:none to the button2 and vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: none;` to the second dashboard styles

```
    #dashboard2 {
      display: none;
      width:800px; 
      height:700px;
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: I tried, although this can remove the second dashboard in the first page, but this will make the second dashboard in the second page also disappear. Any solution to make them display as designed?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the function initialize() {}

```
containerDiv2.style.display = 'none';
```

like

```
    function initialize() {

      var containerDiv1 = document.getElementById("dashboard1"),
      url1 = "https://public.tableau.com/views/liveintegration1/Dashboard1",
      options1 = {
                      hideTabs: true,
                      onFirstInteractive: function () {
                          console.log("Run this code when the viz has finished loading.");
                      }
                  };
      var viz1 = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv1, url1, options1);



      var containerDiv2 = document.getElementById("dashboard2"),
      url2 ="https://public.tableau.com/views/LearnEmbeddedAnalytics/SalesOverviewDashboard",
      options2 = {
                      hideTabs: true,
                      onFirstInteractive: function () {
                          console.log("Run this code when the viz has finished loading.");
                      }
                  };
      var viz2 = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv2, url2, options2);
    containerDiv2.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

Comment: I highly discourage setting specific elements' styles through js: setting a class is smoother and easier as well to read. `#hidden {display:none;} #shown {display: block;}` and then set a class when needed